# How to monitor the JVM of containers and alert on single container usage on AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, containers, monitoring

I've been playing around with a SpringBoot application, the Micrometer façade, the Statsd implementation for Micrometer and the AWS OpenTelemetry distro deployed on ECS/Fargate. So far, I've been able to export many different metrics (JVM, tomcat, data source, etc) to CloudWatch, adding the cluster name, the service name and the task ID as dimensions.

My problem now is that I don't know how to handle that information. In a production deployment I may have more than one container and I may need to scale them out/in. This makes impossible (or at least I don't know how to do it) to create a dashboard as I need to select the task IDs up front. Another problem is that there is no way to add a filter in the dashboard that just shows the list of available task IDs so I can select the one I want to monitor at that moment to remove the noise from the other ones. Something QuickSight can do.

Am I better off just moving to something like Prometheus/Grafana for this? How do people handle monitoring of containers, specially Java applications?

AWS gives you the option to alarm you based on ECS metrics but at the service level (so I guess either based on the average or max of CPU usage for example) but that isn't enough when you have a workload that is not evenly spread across your instances. Is alerting not possible when at the container level (something like alert me when the service is at 60% CPU or a single container is at 80% for example)?

Comment: Have you looked at Amazon [Container Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights.html)? Container Insights provides per-task and per-container metrics, and automatically creates a dashboard for you. You can also build CloudWatch alarms from those metrics. It's a single checkbox to enable Container Insights in your ECS cluster.